# Weighted website rotator

Tags: php

I need a weighted rotator for all links that I create so that traffic can be distributed on a weighted scale to the destinations i define. I currently use the following:

```
<?

header('Location: www.destinationwebsite1.com/index.php');

?>
```

however this only distributes traffic to 1 source.. I want something that distributes based on "weight" to however many destinations i define..

such as:

```
25% to www.destinationwebsite1.com/index.php 
25% to www.destinationwebsite2.com/index.php 
25% to www.destinationwebsite3.com/index.php 
25% to www.destinationwebsite4.com/index.php
```

or whatever percentages i choose. Anyone have any ideas?

Best
-N

Comment: this should be done via Apache, not php [Apache Module mod_proxy_balancer](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html)

Comment: Usually this is done with subdomains (e.g., `www1, www2, www3`), not domains. Also, this is often done with load balancing on the backend, so the user sees one link, but the request is satisfied by one of several "load balancing" servers in the background. A "cloud" setup may also be advantageous (like Amazon's EC2).

Comment: Dagon is very right. Don't do this in code, if this is for load balancing. If that is some affiliate thing, things might be different.

Comment: This is not for load balancing - the destination URL's can be anything. The point is testing various versions of websites to see which perform the best - So i'll have 4 variations i'm testing at once.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`rand`om](http://php.net/rand) number and based on it send your result to a different place.

```
// equal weights:
$sites = Array(
     "http://www.example.com/",
     "http://google.com/",
     "http://youtube.com/"
);
header("Location: ".$sites[rand(0,count($sites)-1)]);

// individual weights:
$sites = Array(
     "http://www.example.com/" => 50,
     "http://google.com/" => 30,
     "http://youtube.com/" => 20
);
$rand = rand(0,array_sum($sites)-1);
foreach($sites as $site=>$weight) {
    $rand -= $weight;
    if( $rand < 0) break;
}
header("Location: ".$site);
```

Comment: If you don't need to have the sites entered dynamically, this is probably a little too overcomplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<?php
$r = rand() / getrandmax();

if ( $r < 0.25 )
{
    header( 'Location: www.destinationwebsite1.com/index.php' );
}
elseif ( $r < 0.50 )
{
    header( 'Location: www.destinationwebsite2.com/index.php' );
}
elseif ( $r < 0.75 )
{
    header( 'Location: www.destinationwebsite3.com/index.php' );
}
else
{
    header( 'Location: www.destinationwebsite4.com/index.php' );
}

?>
```

This should statistically send 25% of your visitors to each site.
To change the ratios of visitors sent to each site, just change the weighting numbers.

Comment: I see repetition. I see repetition. I see repetition. I see repetition.